# Handle Button Clicks in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, button, android-cursoradapter

I want to achieve drop down and sum up for a `View` in my ListView Data is being fetched from the database and am using a cursor adapter, I have tried to add `onClickListner` for the button in `onItemClickListner` But no Success. 
The problem I am facing is When button `DROPDOWN` is clicked it will make `relative layout` Visible but when clicked again it won't `relative layout`  visibility to `GONE`

Heres my Code for CursorAdapter

```
public class ProductViewCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private CardView cv_singleItem;
    private RelativeLayout infoLayout;
    private Button dropDown;
    public ProductViewCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_product_view_listview,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        cv_singleItem = view.findViewById(R.id.cv_custom_single_product);
        infoLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_dropdown_relative);
        dropDown = view.findViewById(R.id.expand_user_info_listView);
        dropDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (infoLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cv_singleItem,new AutoTransition());
                    infoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dropDown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_sumup);
                }else{
                    Log.i("THIS IS TEST","DEMO VIEW "+ infoLayout.getVisibility());
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cv_singleItem,new AutoTransition());
                    infoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dropDown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_dropdown);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ListView single View XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_custom_single_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#D5000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_layout_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_product_image_listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/selimage"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_no_image_available"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No Image Available"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product_name_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Kurti"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/iv_product_image_listView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/expand_user_info_listView"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/iv_product_image_listView"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-49dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_dropdown"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_dropdown_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_date_dropdown_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2020-12-14"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#E2FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_profit_dropdown_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Profit 500"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#E2FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_sellingPrice_dropdown_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Selling Price: 800"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#E2FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_date_dropdown_listView"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_actualPrice_dropDown_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Actual Price: 850"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#E2FFFFFF"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_profit_dropdown_listView"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_pending_dropdown_listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pending: 0"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#F50057"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_sellingPrice_dropdown_listView"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_update_single_item"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_actualPrice_dropDown_listView"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_update"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does the `Log.i("THIS IS TEST","DEMO VIEW "+ infoLayout.getVisibility());` get printed?

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen `Log` gets printed but the `dropDown` button doesn't change nor does the view is gone from the UI, and I am using `LoaderCallback` with `init` method.  Adding this just in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `infoLayout` for every list view row. Every time `bindView()` gets called you replace the `infoLayout` with new layout. This of course causes the problem that when you use `infoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` the `infoLayout` it's not the same layout it was when the list view row was created because you have replaced it.

So replace,

`infoLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_dropdown_relative);`

with

`final RelativeLayout infoLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_dropdown_relative);`

Comment: can you please explain this with an eg. if possible, please. what was my mistake.

Comment: Does my answer work? If it does I can edit my answer and add more details.

Comment: I added a little more detail. Basically you have a variable `infoLayout` which points to `RelativeLayout`. You are replacing the `RelativeLayout` where `infoLayout` points to. This is about how pointers work in java. `CursorAdapter` has nothing to do with the problem.